# Custom Font Gotham Messy With Dynamic Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

How to fix messy custom font with Gotham-Book.ttf in JasperReports?

Custom font arial (succeed):
[image: custom font arial (succeed)]

Font declaration:

```
<fontFamily name="FreeUniversal">
    <normal>jasperutils/fonts/Arial.ttf</normal>
    <bold>jasperutils/fonts/Arial.ttf</bold>
    <italic>jasperutils/fonts/Arial.ttf</italic>
    <boldItalic>jasperutils/fonts/Arial.ttf</boldItalic>
    <pdfEncoding>Cp1252</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
</fontFamily>
```

Custom font Gotham (messy):
[image: custom font Gotham (messy)]

Font declaration:

```
<fontFamily name="FreeUniversal">
    <normal>jasperutils/fonts/gotham/GothamBook.ttf</normal>
    <bold>jasperutils/fonts/gotham/GothamBook.ttf</bold>
    <italic>jasperutils/fonts/gotham/GothamBook.ttf</italic>
    <boldItalic>jasperutils/fonts/gotham/GothamBook.ttf</boldItalic>
    <pdfEncoding>Cp1252</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
</fontFamily>
```

I'm using DynamicReports to generate report, sample code:

```
private void build() {
    FontBuilder defaultFont = stl.font()
        .setFontName("FreeUniversal");
    StyleBuilder boldStyle = stl.style()
        .bold();
    StyleBuilder italicStyle = stl.style()
        .italic();
    StyleBuilder boldItalicStyle = stl.style()
        .boldItalic();

    try {
        report()
            .setDefaultFont(defaultFont)
          .title(
            Templates.createTitleComponent("DefaultFont"),
            cmp.text("FreeUniversal font - plain"),
            cmp.text("FreeUniversal font - bold").setStyle(boldStyle),
            cmp.text("FreeUniversal font - italic").setStyle(italicStyle),
            cmp.text("FreeUniversal font - bolditalic").setStyle(boldItalicStyle))
          .show();
    } catch (DRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```